# spresenseとros1をis110bのwifiを使って通信する方法

Tags: spresense, wifi

現在spresenseで処理した情報をarduino ide，is110bのwifiを使用して，ros1で別のロボットに送信と思っています．micro-rosを使用してros2で通信する方法が存在することはspresenseの公式動画を視聴して確認出来たのですが，ros1環境では見つかりませんでした．現在githubのGS2200-WiFiライブラリをarduino ideにインストールし，TCPClientのサンプルコードを参考にrosserialを使用して通信できないか考えていますが上手く情報を送信出来ない状況です．まだあまり詳しくないため，もし上手くいった方や別の方法があれば教えて頂きたいです．

Comment: すでに試されているようですが、rosserial を改造すれば対応するのは可能だとは思いますが、実装がmicro-ros のように分離されていないので動かすまでに苦労すると思います。単なるコメントになりますが、ROS1はすでに開発は終わっていますし、２５年にはサポートも終了してしまうので、早めにROS2/micro-rosに移行したほうがよいと思います。

Comment: spresense側だけでなくrosserial側のコード改造が必須なことを念頭に入れておらず作業していたため上手くいかなかったのですね．現在通信先の環境がROS1であるためROS1で実行と思っていましたが，仰る通りサポートも終了してしまいわざわざROS1に固守する必要もないため，移行する形で進めていこうと思います．わざわざコメントして頂きありがとうございました．